# Proof of Treeset's clone() creates shallow copy in java?

Tags: java, shallow-copy

I have a doubt, I want to check if TreeSet in java really uses shallow copy for its clone(), but as per my program if I remove a element from parent treeset, its not reflecting in its cloned treeset object.

```
public class TreeSetExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Name> nameTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("Compiere"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("Aristotle"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("CompierE"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("COmpiere"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("ArisTotle"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("arisTotle"));
        nameTreeSet.add(new Name("aristotle"));
        System.out.println(nameTreeSet);

        TreeSet<Name> cloneNameTreeSet = (TreeSet<Name>) nameTreeSet.clone();
        System.out.println(nameTreeSet);
        Iterator<Name> itr = nameTreeSet.iterator();

        /*while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next().getName().equals("aristotle"))
                itr.remove();
        }*/

        for(Name name: nameTreeSet) {
            if(name.getName().equals("aristotle"))
                nameTreeSet.remove(name);
        }

        System.out.println(nameTreeSet);
        System.out.println(cloneNameTreeSet);
    }
}

/*
*Name class which is used in my treeset to store its objects
*/

public class Name implements Cloneable, Comparable<Name>, Comparator<Name> {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [name=" + name + "]";
    }

    private String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Name other = (Name) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Name name1, Name name2) {
        return name1.name.compareTo(name2.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Name name) {
        return (this.name).compareTo(name.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please suggest me, corrections much appreciated :)

Comment: Why would you expect an element to be removed from the cloned instance if you remove it from the original? `clone()` creates a separate instance, with separate state, so changes in the original aren't reflected in the clone (and vice versa)

Comment: A shallow copy is still a copy: you can change one without affecting the other.

Comment: But in shallow copy(TreeSet uses shallow copy as per javadocs) references are copied right? and in my example I'm removing an object of Name class from my original treeset. So it should remove that object from cloned treeset as well.

Comment: "Shallow Copy In Java :

The default version of clone() method creates the shallow copy of an object. The shallow copy of an object will have exact copy of all the fields of original object. If original object has any references to other objects as fields, then only references of those objects are copied into clone object, copy of those objects are not created. That means any changes made to those objects through clone object will be reflected in original object or vice-versa. Shallow copy is not 100% disjoint from original object. Shallow copy is not 100% independent of original object."

Comment: this is the definition I found for Shallow copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I remove a element from parent treeset, its not reflecting in its cloned treeset object.

You are misunderstanding what shallow copy means. It means that for each element of the `TreeSet`, the reference is copied to the new `TreeSet`. So if you mutate one of the `Name` objects located in one `Set`, the corresponding element in the other `Set` will also be mutated, since both refer to the same object.

For example, this will affect both `Set`s :

```
    for(Name name: nameTreeSet) {
        if(name.getName().equals("aristotle"))
            name.setName("new name");
    }
```

However, the cloned `TreeSet` is a different object than the original `TreeSet`, and removing elements from one doesn't affect the other. Removing elements from one `Set` would affect the other only if instead of cloning you just copy the reference - `TreeSet<Name> cloneNameTreeSet = nameTreeSet;`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but now I'm still confused with shallow copy and deep copy, please help me to understand better

Comment: @arafath Deep copy would mean that the copy of the original TreeSet would contain copies of all the Name elements (instead of references to the same Name elements stored in the original TreeSet).